# Use javascript function variable in another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have a JavaSript function i want to use this function's variable in an another function

**Function 1:**

```
 function datevalue(){
    var params = {};
    var val = document.getElementById("dateRange").value;

    if (val.length > 0) {
        var dateArray = val.split("TO");
        if (dateArray.length > 1) {
            params.fromDate = dateArray[0];
            params.endDate = dateArray[1];
        } else {
            params.fromDate = dateArray[0];
            params.endDate = null;
        }
    } else {
        params.fromDate = null;
        params.endDate = null;
    }
    params.segment = $('#segments').val();

}
```

**Function 2:**

```
function getAgewisedistributiont() {
    var trendUrl = '<s:url value="/campaign/getUserEachSegmentSegmentDashboard" />';
    $.post(trendUrl, params, function(data) {});
}
```

Comment: It is not clear exactly what your problem is that you want help with.  Please explain the problem in more detail.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i need to use varilbke array param in to another function

Comment: What is a "varilbke array param"?

Comment: The way the entire question is spelled, it looks more like a spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the `param` as below

```
function datevalue(){
          var params = {};
        var val = document.getElementById("dateRange").value;

    if (val.length > 0) {
        var dateArray = val.split("TO");

        if (dateArray.length > 1) {
            params.fromDate = dateArray[0];
            params.endDate = dateArray[1];

        } else {
            params.fromDate = dateArray[0];
            params.endDate = null;

        }
    } else {
        params.fromDate = null;
        params.endDate = null;

    }
    params.segment = $('#segments').val();
    return params;
}
```

And update the function as below

```
function getAgewisedistributiont() {
     var returnedparams = datevalue(); // variable returnedparams will hold the returned value
     var trendUrl = '<s:url value="/campaign/getUserEachSegmentSegmentDashboard" />';
        $.post(trendUrl, returnedparams, function(data) {  });
}
```

Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to learn the fundamentals of scoping. 
Javascript [Documentation](http://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/).

For your provided example you can use hoisting to pull a variable out of a scope layer above it.

```
//Variable to hoist
var _data;

function instantiateData() {
   //Setting data
   _data = "I am alive";
}

function logData() {
   //Using data
   alert(_data);
   console.log(_data);
}

instantiateData();
logData();
```

Fiddle [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/29nno800/1/).